# Ace Editor - Autocomplete to Fire When I Press White-Space

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

Auto-complete is not getting fired when pressing white-space in the editor, Is there an option to fire Autocomplete when white space is pressed?
Please have a look at this demo:

```
    [jsfiddle] https://jsfiddle.net/xbaha/cbfe6tx4/53/
```

I want the auto complete to be fired when i type "my name is " (note there is a space after "is"), then using onchange event i added the suggestions that should pop up, but it does not work, i must type a letter character so that autocomplete is getting fired.

is there a solution for this?

Comment: Do you want auto-complete to be fired every time when the user presses white-space?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using enableLiveAutocomplete option you can use a custom handler for afterExec event https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.4.7/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L149

```js
var editor;
var fieldsList = [];

function initAceEditor() {
  editor = ace.edit("aceEditor", {
    theme: "ace/theme/solarized_light",
    mode: "ace/mode/text",
    showPrintMargin: false,
    fontSize: "24px",

    minLines: 3,
    maxLines: 8,
    wrap: true,
    // do not use live autocomplete since we want to invoke more often
    // enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
  });
  var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");


  var stepLineCompleter = {
    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
      var completions = [];
      console.log('before foreach....', this.fields, fieldsList);
      var cursor = session.selection.cursor
      var line = session.getLine(cursor.row).slice(0, cursor.column - prefix.length)
      var fieldsList
      if (line.endsWith("name is ")) {
        fieldsList = ["bob", "james", "alex", "jimmy"];
      } else {
        fieldsList = ["my name is", "completion2", "completion3", "one more"]
      }
      fieldsList.forEach(function(w) {
        completions.push({
          value: w,
        });
      });
      callback(null, completions);
    }
  }

  langTools.setCompleters([stepLineCompleter]);
  langTools.addCompleter(stepLineCompleter);
  var Autocomplete = ace.require("ace/autocomplete").Autocomplete
  var doLiveAutocomplete = function(e) {
    var editor = e.editor;
    var hasCompleter = editor.completer && editor.completer.activated;
    var session = editor.session
    var cursor = session.selection.cursor
    var line = session.getLine(cursor.row).slice(0, cursor.column)

    // We don't want to autocomplete with no prefix
    if (e.command.name === "backspace") {
      // do not hide after backspace
    } else if (e.command.name === "insertstring") {
      if (!hasCompleter) {
        // always start completer
        var completer = Autocomplete.for(editor);
        // Disable autoInsert
        completer.autoInsert = false;
        completer.showPopup(editor);
      }
    }
  };

  editor.commands.on('afterExec', doLiveAutocomplete);


}

initAceEditor()
```

```css
#aceEditor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>



<div id="aceEditor"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it actually worked, but i got another problem, the Autocomplete popup did not come up during the word, I must click the white space, for example, my search is for "my name is" (without space), it pushes the autocomplete values, but nothing shows up, I made a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/xbaha/0g8a1yn3/16/   , please type my name is, check the console that shows call back made with autocomplete words.